# Problem with simple dice game using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, dice

I'm new to python so I decided to make a simple dice game using a while loop just to do a simple test of myself. In the game, I use the module random and the method `random.randint(1, 6)` to print a random integer of any value from "1 to 6", which is evidently how a dice works in real life. But to make this a game, if the integer that is printed is even `(random.randint(1, 6) % 2 ==0)` then 'you win' is printed. If the integer is odd, then 'you lose' is printed. After this, the console asks if you want to roll the dice again, and if you say yes (not case sensitive hence `.lower()`) then it rolls again and the loop continues, but if you say anything else the loop breaks.

I thought this is was how it would work, but every now and then, when an even number is rolled, 'you lose' is printed, and the opposite for odd numbers, which is not what I thought I had coded my loop to do. Obviously I'm doing something wrong. Can anyone help?

This is my code:

```
import random
min = 1
max = 6

roll_again = True
while roll_again:
    print(random.randint(min, max))
    if random.randint(min, max) % 2 == 0:
        print('you win')

    else:
        print('you lose')

    again = input('roll the dice? ').lower()
    if again == ('yes'):
        continue
    else:
        print('ok')
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(random.randint(min, max))
if random.randint(min, max) % 2 == 0:
    print('you win')
```

Those are two *separate* calls to `randint()`, likely producing two different numbers.

Instead, call `randint()` *once* and save the result, then use that one result in both places:

```
roll = random.randint(min, max)
print(roll)
if roll % 2 == 0:
    print('you win')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are generating a random number twice, the number printed isn't the same the number as the one you are checking in the if condition.

You can save the number generated in a variable like this to check if your code is working fine :

```
import random
min = 1
max = 6

roll_again = True
while roll_again:
    number = random.randint(min, max)
    print(number)
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print('you win')

else:
    print('you lose')

again = input('roll the dice? ').lower()
if again == ('yes'):
    continue
else:
    print('ok')
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign random number to a variable, right now printed and the other one are different numbers.

```py
import random
min = 1
max = 6
dice = 0

while True: 
    dice = random.randint(min, max) 
    print(dice) 
 
    if dice % 2 == 0: 
        print('you win') 
    else: 
        print('you lose') 

    again = input('roll the dice? ').lower() 
    if again == ('yes'): 
        continue 
    else: 
        print('ok') 
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

random.randint(min,max) returns different value every time it is executed. So, the best thing you can do is store the value at the very first execution and check on that stored value for Win or Loss.

You can try this version of code:

```
import random

while(True):
    value = random.randint(1,6)
    print(value)
    if(value % 2 == 0):
        print("You Win!")
    else:
        print("You Lose!")

    again = input("Want to roll Again? Type 'Yes' or 'No'")
    if(again.lower() != 'yes'):
        break
```